# Strange constrained_width behaviour with TextView

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout

basically I have an layout as shown in the image. I am using a Guideline to restrict the width of the blue box. This means the ConstraintLayout itself hase full screen width and the blue box has its `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"`.

The blue box is just the background color of the TextView with the text, there aren't any additional containers or anything.

In order for the blue box to respect the constraints for its width calculations I have to set `layout_constrainedWidth="true"` on the box. As you can see the width is then restricted but the problem is that wrap_content does not work correctly afterwards.

The first box shows that if the text is only a single line, then the behaviour is as expected but if the text spans multiple lines (as in the second box) wrap_content breaks and the box is always "full width" (start of screen until the guideline).

Did somebody experience something similar? Is this a bug or did I misunderstood something. The same broken behaviour can be observed with the grey box on the right side.

I assume this has to do with the breaking behaviour of the TextView but is there a fix or workaround? As far as I know outside of an ConstraintLayout the width would be equal to the text so I assume this is a bug.

[image]

Edit XML code:
This is the basice code of one of the "bubbles" and as already mentioned I would like the view to really be as wide as the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_message_history_receiver_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        tools:text="Just testing something, somehowthisisnotworking" />

    <app.jooy.messenger.ui.components.generic.profile_image.ProfileImage
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the output of this particular xml code:
[image]

Comment: I think you want that if text length exceeds then it should be before the guideline but if it less then it should be a wrap. 
So for a single line, it is working fine but for multiple lines, it is taking till guideline.

try adding this property.
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"

Comment: @KishanMaurya Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately your suggestion of adding app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap" did not change anything. Do you have any other idea what I could try?

Comment: XML code required to study the issue.

Comment: @rahat I added the basic xml code of the "bubble"

Comment: @MaxGierlachowski you want the image plus text view's width to cover 80 percent of the width of the parent, right?

Comment: @MaxGierlachowski, check out the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, adjust margin and padding as per your need. and change the `android:layout_marginBottom` of the `guide` as per your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guide"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
        tools:text="Just testing something, Some how this is not working" />

     <app.jooy.messenger.ui.components.generic.profile_image.ProfileImage
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/guide"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/profile_image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```